# "Could not find stored procedure 'ÿþ' " error

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014, utf-16, windows-1252

I am trying to execute a query, after reading the content from a SQL Script file, assigning it to a variable and then executing the content. Then I get this error saying `Could not find stored procedure 'ÿþ'`. Please help me understand the issue. Thank you.

**Info:**

> SQL Server 2014
>
> SSMS Version - 12.0.4100.1

Comment: The issue is that your SQL Script File is encoded as UTF-16 and the part of your application that reads it decodes it as Windows-1252.

Comment: Oh I see. What can I do to get over it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ÿþ` is one way to interpret the two bytes of the the [UTF-16 byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16), which is \xFF and \xFE.

You get those two letters when you read a file that has been saved in the UTF-16 encoding with a tool that is unaware of—or, more likely, was not configured to use—Unicode.

For example, when you edit a text file with Windows Notepad and select "Unicode" as file encoding when you save it, Notepad will use UTF-16 to save the file and will mark it with the said two bytes at the start.

If whatever thing you use to read the file is unaware of the fact that the file is Unicode, then it will use the default byte encoding of your computer to decode that text file.

Now, if that default encoding happens to be [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), like in your case, then `ÿþ` is what you get, because there \xFF is `ÿ` and \xFE is `þ`.

Consequently, when presented with `ÿþ`, SQL Server thinks it must be the name of a stored procedure, because stored procedures are the only statements that you can run by mentioning just their name. And it dutifully reports that it can't find a procedure of that name.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now I understand why it's happening. Is there any way to skip those characters?

Comment: You absolutely don't want to skip those characters. They are important.

Comment: I've explained everything you need to know to come to the right conclusion about what to do. Piece the puzzle together, it's not difficult. :)

Comment: The key phrase is between the two dashes.

Comment: xD Ok. You are being really helpful. I'll try your solution... :)

Comment: I just don't want to write it out. Things have a much deeper impact when you get the "Aha!" moment yourself.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I see what you mean... :) :) Thanks for the help so far anyway... :)